# How to make a window smaller than 125 x 50 in Java?

Tags: java, swing, window, awt

I'm trying to create a 50x50 window in Java but the window won't go smaller than 125x50, even if I try to manually resize it.

Here's my code currently:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class smallwindow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setSize(50, 50);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am running this with the latest version of Java on Mac OS X.
Is there any way to do this with a JFrame, or would I need to use something else, like maybe AWT?

**edit: is there a way to do this while retaining the titlebar, window management buttons, etc.?

Comment: What is the point of such a small free floating window?  (Don't get me wrong, I guess they have valid uses, I'm just curious as to what your use-case is.)

Comment: don't think it's possible - looks like the frame's minimum size is OS-defined such that the OS-provided decorations (title icon, title buttons and frame-border) fits. So either undecorated (as @E-Z suggested) or Window. Just as @Andrew, would be interested in the why - while the undecorated style doesn't care if the buttons are visible or not, it doesn't feel very useful ;-)

Comment: On Mac OS X, using `setLayout(null); pack()` reduces the height to 35 pixels, but the width remains unchanged.

Comment: @Albert `ClassNames` in Java should be `UpperCamelCase`, in your example, it should be `SmallWindow`

Comment: @kleopatra well, I tried resizing the windows of other applications, such as Firefox and Terminal, and all of them have different minimum dimensions. Though it's possible that Swing/AWT were written so that minimum dimensions can't be changed

Comment: @Albert thanks for the info - just tried on mine (Vista, firefox) and have the same minimum restriction (that is, no smaller than showing the title buttons)

Answer (score 3):

You would have to do the following on the `JFrame`:

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: You might just as well use a `JWindow` in the first place.

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to do this such that you still retain the tilebar, window management buttons, etc.?

Comment: I do not know of a way to change the size of the window management buttons, which would make the overall window size smaller. My other suggestion would be to `extend JDialog`. You would have the close button and an icon which could reduce the size some and still retain a title bar.

Comment: An ugly alternate would be `frame.setUndecorated(true); frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME); frame.setSize(50,50);` As soon as the frame would be resized, the min width issue would happen again.

Comment: For extending JDialog, could you give an example? Because JDialogs have the same size restrictions as JFrames. For your second idea, I tried it, but nothing changed...

Comment: Extending a JDialog tutorial can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ExtendingJDialog.htm). I have to believe that the OS is forcing the sizing issues on you, these techniques work at least in Vista. Sorry I can't provide an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Guys, I did a little more looking into it, apparently there is a method called `setMinimumSize`

Basically, all you need to do is add

```
Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(50, 50);  
frame.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);`
```

I've found that if the size is less than about 75x75, then resizing it will suddenly change the minimum width to around 75. The solution is to just to do `frame.setResizable(false)`

But anyways, thanks for all your help!

Comment: I forgot to mention, but you need to import java.awt.Dimension;

Comment: just for the record: didn't work (had tried before, actually :-) on my machine (Vista). But good to know it might somewhere else, thanks

Comment: actually yeah, you're right. I tried this on Windows Vista and 7, both times the size of the window was still 125x50...

Answer (score 0):

> but is there anyway to do this such that you still retain the tilebar, window management buttons, etc.?

You can use the Metal LAF which includes the title bar:

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work, there was no change in look for the window, and the size stayed at 125x50

Comment: @Albert, Then it must be a version or platform issue. I'm using JDK6_7 on XP. I added the single line of code to the start of your 3 line program. The window displayed at 50x50 which meant that not even all the buttons where visible.

Comment: I get @Albert's result on Mac OS X, which enforces a minimum window size; I'm not certain of the mechanism.